# Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion' (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, completionhandler

In my project, I came across a situation when I need to use the background queue to create an AVPlayerItem (which I create in `setupTrackModels` function). I'd like do it in `getTracks` function, and this method must also have a completion handler which I need to call in main thread, but I cannot make them friends in any way. I get compiler error: `Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'` Maybe someone can tell me how to do this or show another way.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var content: [URL] = []
var tracks: [TrackModelProtocol] = []

private func getTracks(completion: () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { //Error: Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'
        self.tracks = self.setupTrackModels(content: self.content)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async { //Error: Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'completion'
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

And then I'd like to use the function like this:

```
getTracks {
   tableView.reloadData()
   //or something else
}
```

I don't want to use `tableView.reloadData()` in the DispatchQueue.main. block because I call `getTracks` several times and I want to implement different logic in it's completion block

Comment: You need to mark the `completion` parameter as `@escaping`

Comment: FWIW, as a matter of convention, we now generally use `Void` rather than `()` for the closures return type, e.g. `func getTracks(completion: @escaping () -> Void) { ... }`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `@escaping`

```
private func getTracks(completion:@escaping () -> ())
```

Comment: How do you think, is it a good practice to use a completion handler in the DispatchQueue. block? Or I must find a better way?

Comment: yes , it's commonly used with an asynchronous operation